# Only navigate to next page when asynchronos actions are complete? React-native

Tags: react-native, redux

So, I have a bit of a tricky situation here for me as a beginner with redux as well as react-native.

When the user loggs in, I want to update the Redux state with the user data. I call a login methond where I get a web token. Directly afterwards I want to dispatch two asynchronous actions with redux-thunk. The problem is:

By the time these actions are dispatched and I have the response from the API, I've already navigated to another screen and the data to render the list is not in the Redux state.

**The Question:** How can I "hold" the program until my state is updated and then navigate to the next page?

This is what happens when the user logs in:

```
 fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/api-token-auth/", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.props.email,
          password: this.props.password,
        })
        }).then((response) => response.json()
        ).then((jResponse) => {
          console.log(jResponse);
          this._onValueChange('token_id', jResponse.token);
          this.props.loginUserSuccess();
          this.props.navigation.navigate('MainMenue');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.props.loginUserFail();
          })   
    }
```

Somewhere during the login these two actions sould be dispatched completly and the state should be updated:

```
export const profileLoad = () => {       

        return (dispatch) => {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('token_id')
            .then((token_id) => fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/profile/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token_id
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((answer) => {
                dispatch({ type: PROFILE_LOAD, payload: answer});
            })
            .done());
        }  
    }

export const productsLoad = () => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token_id')
        .then((token_id) => {

            fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/profile/products/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token_id
                }
            }).then((anser) => anser.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                dispatch ({ type: PRODUCTS_LOAD, payload: response})
            })
        }
        ).done();
    }  

}
```

Then I want to navigate the another screen andrender a list (with ListView) to display the JSON data from products and profiles.

-- > So I finally figured it out. 
**Solution**
1.) Return promises from action creators as stated 
2.) Make sure you put a callback function in the then method

```
export const loadAllProfileData = ({navigate}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(profileLoad())
        .then(() => dispatch(productsLoad()))
        .then(() => navigate('MainMenue'))
    };
}

export const profileLoad = () => {       

            return (dispatch) => {
                return AsyncStorage.getItem('token_id')
                .then((token_id) => fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/profile/", {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token_id
                    }
                })
                ).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((answer) => {
                    dispatch({ type: PROFILE_LOAD, payload: answer});
                })

            }  
        }


export const productsLoad = () => {

     return (dispatch) => {
         return AsyncStorage.getItem('token_id')
         .then((token_id) => 
             fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/profile/products/", {
                 method: "GET",
                 headers: {
                 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token_id
                 }
            })
        ).then((answer) => answer.json())
        .then((response)=> {
                dispatch ({ type: PRODUCTS_LOAD, payload: response})
            }) 

     }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return promises from your action creators and `chain` them with `then`. You can do that by simply adding `return AsyncStorage.getItem() ...` to your action creators. Then you can do:

```
fetch(url) //login
  .then(dispatch(profileLoad))
  .then(dispatch(productsLoad))
  .then(this.props.navigation.navigate('MainMenue'))
  .catch(err => //handle error)
```

Read more about [promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

Edit: A simple example would be:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA';

const url = `${ROOT_URL}/users`;

function fetchData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_DATA,
                    payload: data[0].name
                });
            }) 
    }
}

function reducer(state = [], action) {
    if (action.type === FETCH_DATA) {
        console.log('Action.payload:', action.payload);
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
            return [...state, action.payload];

        default:
            return state;
    };
}

let store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)

store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log('Store State: ', store.getState())
)

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data)
    .then(store.dispatch(fetchData()))
    .then(store.dispatch(fetchData()))
```

Comment: So right now the action creators are returning : `return AsyncStorage.getItem()` do you mean, to delete all calls to dispatch and not to return a callback function? It seems confusing to me because in the action creater some sort of action has to be dispatched ...

Comment: You will leave the dispatchs as they are, the reason to return a Promise is that you can wait for the fetch to `resolve` before you go to the next one.

Comment: sorry for all these stupid questions. But the dispatch function is supplied by the thunk middleware, right? I can nut just simply call it on the component level? Does the login has to be a redux action as well? There I used component level state. Right now I simply getting that `dispatch` is not defined.

Comment: Yes, the dispatch function can be used because of thunk. You can call it on the component level if you pass it using redux `connect`. The login doesn't have to be a redux action if you don't want to use dispatch inside it. Edited my answer with a simple example where I use a fetch that is not a thunk, followed by two thunks. LMK if you can't understand something.

Comment: I spent much more time on this problem then I'd like to admit to anyone. I posted the updated code to my original question. But it just wont work.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks for the help. I updated my question with the solution that worked for me.